# Continuity of the operator

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $D: (C^1[a,b], \Vert .\Vert_1 )\rightarrow (C[a,b], \Vert .\Vert_1)$ with $D(f)=f^{\prime}$

I wonder if I will be continuing this operator

Note: $\Vert f\Vert_1=\int_a^b\vert f(x)\vert dx$

All suggestions are welcome

Comment: Did you try functions like $f_n(x) = \cos(nx)$? (Let say $[a,b] = [-\pi, \pi]$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to the question:

*Does restricting the $\|\cdot\|_1$-norm of $f$ restrict the $\|\cdot\|_1$-norm of $f'$?*

At least for the *suprememum* norm $\|.\|_\infty$, we know this *not* to the case - we can easily find functions withwith arbitrarily large derivative which nevertheless obey $\|f\|_\infty \leq 1$, for example $f(x) = \sin nx$.

The same counter-example works for the $\|\cdot\|_1$-norm too. To be able to easily express the $1$-norm of $f'$ in terms of the $1$-norm of $f$, we modify the example slightly and set $$
  f(x) = \sin (nx) + \cos (nx) \text{,}
$$
and let $a=-c$, $b=c$. Then $$
  \|f\|_1 = \int_{-c}^c |\sin nx + \cos nx| \,dx \leq 2(c - (-c)) = 4c
$$
but, using the substitution $u=-x$, $$
  \|f'\|_1 = |n|\int_{-c}^c |\cos nx - \sin nx| \,dx
  = |n|\int_c^{-c} -|\cos nu + \sin nu| \,du = |n|\cdot \|f\|_1 \text{.}
$$

Comment: @helmonio You're welcome. Note that to make this work for arbitrary $a,b$, you'll have to modify $f(x)$ appropriately.